# MYSQL error Unknown column in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I need the last record for the last date, i have the following query

```
SELECT creditos.NombreCliente,
creditos.Contrato, 
creditos.Rut, 
creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza, 
creditos.FechaPagare, 
creditos.FechaCurse, 
creditos.FechaVcto1, 
creditos.FechaVcto2, 
creditos.FormaPago, 
creditos.EstadoMandato,
REPLACE(CuentaCorriente,',','.') as CuentaCorriente , 
creditos.Sucursal, 
creditos.cFyI, 
creditos.FechaUltimoPago, 
estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Activación` AS FechaActivacion, estado_creditos_banco.`Detalle de Rechazo` AS DetalleRechazo, MAX(estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA`), estado_activos_banco.Observaciones, estado_creditos_banco.`Estado General` AS EstadoActivacion, 
creditos.EmailCliente,
REPLACE(creditos.TelefonosCliente,',','-') as Telefono  
FROM creditos 
LEFT JOIN estado_creditos_banco ON estado_creditos_banco.Identificador = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza 
LEFT JOIN estado_activos_banco ON estado_activos_banco.`# Cotiz` = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza 
WHERE `creditos`.`Estado` = "CURSADA" 
AND 1=1  
GROUP BY Identificador 
HAVING estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA` = MAX(estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA`) 
LIMIT 0,300
```

throws me the following error

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'estado_creditos_banco.Fecha Recepción CCA' in 'having clause'

help me please

Comment: Formatting your code to be human-readable will help you, as a human, read it.  Being able to meaningfully read and understand code is an important step toward correcting it.

Comment: Are you sure your field is not `Fecha Activación`  instead of   `Fecha Recepción CCA`  ?
Note that I don't think that using non ASCII char is a good idea in table names

Comment: clearly not a good idea, but the problem is with the sentence having, not with the format of the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found the solution, rename the variable date and change it in the sentence having.

```
SELECT
    creditos.NombreCliente,
    creditos.Contrato,
    creditos.Rut,
    creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza,
    creditos.FechaPagare,
    creditos.FechaCurse,
    creditos.FechaVcto1,
    creditos.FechaVcto2,
    creditos.FormaPago,
    creditos.EstadoMandato,
    REPLACE (CuentaCorriente, ',', '.') AS CuentaCorriente,
    creditos.Sucursal,
    creditos.cFyI,
    creditos.FechaUltimoPago,
    estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Activación` AS FechaActivacion,
    estado_creditos_banco.`Detalle de Rechazo` AS DetalleRechazo,
    MAX(
        estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA`
    ) as fecha,
    estado_activos_banco.Observaciones,
    estado_creditos_banco.`Estado General` AS EstadoActivacion,
    creditos.EmailCliente,
    REPLACE (
        creditos.TelefonosCliente,
        ',',
        '-'
    ) AS Telefono
FROM
    creditos
LEFT JOIN estado_creditos_banco ON estado_creditos_banco.Identificador = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza
LEFT JOIN estado_activos_banco ON estado_activos_banco.`# Cotiz` = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza
WHERE
    `creditos`.`Estado` = "CURSADA"
AND 1 = 1
GROUP BY
    Identificador
HAVING
    fecha = MAX(
        estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA`
    )
LIMIT 0,
 300
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your having close like this : 
 `HAVING FechaRecep = MAX(estado_creditos_banco.Fecha )`  
so your query should look like :

```
SELECT creditos.NombreCliente, creditos.Contrato, creditos.Rut, 
  creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza, creditos.FechaPagare, creditos.FechaCurse,
  creditos.FechaVcto1, creditos.FechaVcto2, creditos.FormaPago, creditos.EstadoMandato,
  REPLACE(CuentaCorriente,',','.') as CuentaCorriente , creditos.Sucursal, creditos.cFyI, 
  creditos.FechaUltimoPago, estado_creditos_banco.Fecha Activación AS FechaActivacion,
  estado_creditos_banco.Detalle de Rechazo AS DetalleRechazo, 
  MAX(estado_creditos_banco.Fecha) as maxFecha, 
   estado_activos_banco.Observaciones, 
  estado_creditos_banco.Estado General AS EstadoActivacion, creditos.EmailCliente,
  REPLACE(creditos.TelefonosCliente,',','-') as Telefono,
  MAX(estado_creditos_banco.`Fecha Recepción CCA`) as FechaRecep 

  FROM creditos 

    LEFT JOIN estado_creditos_banco 
       ON estado_creditos_banco.Identificador = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza 
    LEFT JOIN estado_activos_banco 
        ON estado_activos_banco.# Cotiz = creditos.lIdtplCabezaCotiza 

  WHERE creditos.Estado = "CURSADA" 
        AND 1=1 GROUP BY Identificador 

  HAVING FechaRecep = maxFecha

  LIMIT 0,300
```

Comment: does not work the having, because the field DateRecep does not exist in the table, I need to obtain the record of the maximum date of Fecha Recepción CCA

Comment: I think your talking about FechaRecep 
  and not DateRecep because i don't see this variable here. i changed my answer !

Comment: i still have the error [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'estado_creditos_banco.Fecha' in 'having clause'